# Easy: Solve T(n)=T(n-1)+n by Iteration Method

Tags: algorithm, iteration

Can someone please help me with this ?

> **Use iteration method to solve it.**  T(n) = T(n-1) +n

Explanation of steps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you required to use a specific programming language or are you asking for pseudo code?

Comment: pseudo code..and thanks for the instant reply ! :D

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Are you familiar with recursion?

Comment: @cruxi No, I am not. Not completely.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n

T(n-1) = T(n-2) + n-1

T(n-2) = T(n-3) + n-2
```

and so on you can substitute the value of T(n-1) and T(n-2) in T(n) to get a general idea of the pattern.

```
T(n) = T(n-2) + n-1 + n

T(n) = T(n-3) + n-2 + n-1 + n
.
.
.

T(n) = T(n-k) + kn - k(k-1)/2    ...(1)
```

For base case:

```
n - k = 1 so we can get T(1)
```

=> k = n - 1
substitute in (1)

```
  T(n) = T(1) + (n-1)n - (n-1)(n-2)/2
```

Which you can see is of Order n<sup>2</sup> => O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 9):

Expand it!

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n = T(n-2) + (n-1) + n = T(n-3) + (n-2) + (n-1) + n
```

and so on, until

```
T(n) = 1 + 2 + ... + n = n(n+1)/2   [= O(n^2)]
```

provided that `T(1) = 1`

Comment: Are you sure that this is O(n²) ?

Comment: @ralu to be more precise, it Theta(n²), since n² bounds it from above and from below.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n
     = T(n-2) + n-1 + n
     = T(n-3) + n-2 + n-1 + n
     // we can now generalize to k
     = T(n-k) + n-k+1 + n-k+2 + ... + n-1 + n
     // since n-k = 1 so T(1) = 1
     = 1 + 2 + ... + n    //Here 
     = n(n-1)/2
     = n^2/2 - n/2
     // we take the dominating term which is n^2*1/2 therefor 1/2 = big O
     = big O(n^2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo code using iteration:

```
function T(n) {
    int result = 0;

    for (i in 1 ... n) {
       result = result + i;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: i wanted to thank you but it says i need 15 rep. thank you :D

Answer (score -2):

**Easy Method:**

```
T (n) = T (n - 1) + (n )-----------(1)
 //now submit T(n-1)=t(n)

T(n-1)=T((n-1)-1)+((n-1))
T(n-1)=T(n-2)+n-1---------------(2)

now submit (2) in (1) you will get
i.e T(n)=[T(n-2)+n-1]+(n)
T(n)=T(n-2)+2n-1 //simplified--------------(3)

 now, T(n-2)=t(n)
T(n-2)=T((n-2)-2)+[2(n-2)-1]
  T(n-2)=T(n-4)+2n-5---------------(4)
  now submit (4) in (2) you will get
   i.e T(n)=[T(n-4)+2n-5]+(2n-1)
  T(n)=T(n-4)+4n-6 //simplified
    ............
 T(n)=T(n-k)+kn-6
  **Based on General form T(n)=T(n-k)+k, **
  now, assume n-k=1 we know T(1)=1
            k=n-1

    T(n)=T(n-(n-1))+(n-1)n-6
    T(n)=T(1)+n^2-n-10
   According to the complexity 6 is constant

         So , Finally O(n^2)
```

Comment: Please don't resurrect old-dead low-quality questions.

Comment: I was given an easy steps to get the answer .. i know it too long but it not resurrect  @YSC

Comment: you really killed it :/ 
"We know T(1) = 0" ?
in order to have k=n-1 you need to have T(1) = 1 thus n-k=1 => k = n-1